# VBA: Runtime error 438

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy the range D11:N11 from Sheet 1 to a varying range on Background Sheet. The columns stay the same but the rows vary depending on the value in cell B2. The value in cell B2 is determined by using `="D"&[reference cell]&":N"[reference cell]` showing a value somewhere between `D2:N2` and `D53:N53`.

If I run the macro below I get the 438 error (This property or method is not supported by this object) at the line with the asterisks.

How should I change my code?

```
Sub IndirectCellSelect()

Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Sheets("Background Sheet").Range("B2")


With ThisWorkbook

    With Sheets("Sheet 1")

        .Range("D11:N11").Copy


    With Sheets("Background Sheet")

        .Range(rng1.Text).Paste  ***

    End With
    End With

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Copy` >> `Paste` is a 1 line code line.

Also, since you already `Set rng1` you can directly `Paste` to the value in it.

```
Sub IndirectCellSelect()

Dim rng1 As Range

With ThisWorkbook
    Set rng1 = .Sheets("Background Sheet").Range(Range("B2").Value)
    .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D11:N11").Copy Destination:=rng1
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D11:N11").Copy Destination:=rng1 requires a period between ThisWorkbook and Sheets(. The With statement doesn't make much sense in the above construction, but if it is to be used the period before Sheets( can't be omitted.

Comment: Hi Shai Rado and Variatus, thank you for your input. I tried your code and it worked for the D2:N2 value of B2. But as soon as I change it (for example D3:N3) I get a new error message: 'Error 1004 Copy method of Range Class Failed'

Comment: Nevermind, I see what I did wrong. It works fine now. Thanks again

Comment: @ShaiRado I do have an additional question:

Can I use the same method to copy the values I pasted this way to the source cells? Something along the line of:

Sub Reverse()
    
Dim rng2 As Range

With ThisWorkbook
    Set rng2 = .Sheets("Background Sheet").Range(Range("B2").Value)
    rng2.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D11:N11")
    
End With
    
    
End Sub

Comment: @Leon did you try ? let me know if it works (VBA doesn't bite ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado I did and it returned with all cells blank

Comment: @ShaiRado Again I have found my own error. I should search before I ask apparently. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Sub IndirectCellSelect()

   Dim rng1 As Range
   Set rng1 = Sheets("Background Sheet").Range("B2")

   Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("D11:N11").Copy Destination:=Range(rng1.Text)

End Sub
```

Also, you will want your B2 cell formula to include the `:` before the `N`:

```
="D"&[reference cell]&":N"[reference cell]
```

Comment: Hi CLR, perceptive of you. I have added the ':'

Comment: No problem Leon. I've just noticed that my answer does something different to Shai's. Have I misunderstood your question? Shai's answer appears to paste the data into B2, whereas my answer pastes the question into the cell address held in B2.